# Run a file before py.test session starts, without __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

**Is there a way to run a .py at the very beginning besides `__init__.py`?**

My problem is I need to save the current database state before the parsing of the files changes things.  Because I have temporary tests variables that change, but if I can store the state before parsing this would be fixed since I can just restore it at the end of the session.

**I need to run a .py not just before the actual test session starts but before the other files are parsed.**

example:

`console> py.test tests/test_example.py`
 - need it to run here
`collecting 0 items`
`tests/test_example.py`
`==== test session starts ====`
`conftest.py` runs here

You could say that an `__init__.py` would be a solution but when there is an `__init__.py` in the testing directory, pytest runs everything as a module. (instead of running from `py._path.pyimport`, it runs from `__init__.py`) This breaks all my tests and imports throughout my whole tests/ directory

So maybe I can crate my own `py._path.pyimport`, this just doesn't seem to be the safest/correct way. Or is it possible to call an `__init__.py` and still run from `py._path.pyimport` after?

Comment: Why not write a script that saves the state, runs your test, and then restores the state?

Comment: Well other people will need to run these tests, I guess I could put the script file in the same filespace and just run that from the console with some input to customize how I want the test to be run. Still It would be useful if I could do somehybrid of ` __init__ `and `py._path.pyimport` function

Comment: Still in python would be good

Comment: Is this script started directly or by another Python script?

Comment: I'm thinking in terms of [`if __name__ == "main":`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)  and then do your state saving there before starting the test.

Comment: okay I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: Can you decouple your unit tests from the database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use pytest's [plugin hooks](http://pytest.org/latest/writing_plugins.html) with a `conftest.py` to do so.

I'm not sure which hook would be best for your case. Probably `pytest_configure`.

For example, with this in a `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_configure():
    print("Hello World")
```

you get:

```
$ py.test
Hello World!
=================== test session starts ====================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.1, pytest-2.9.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
[..]

collecting 120 items
```

Comment: wouldn't the hooks run after the test session starts? I need it to run during or before initialization

Comment: Depends on what initialization you mean, but pytest is heavily based on hooks, e.g. even the test session itself is just a set of (internal) hooks.

Comment: as stated in the question? Initialization meaning at __init__.py at the very beginning of parsing. Way before the test session even starts. hooks can config the test but can only be run once the test session starts, correct?

Comment: That's wrong. You can influence things as early as pytest's commandline parsing for example. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Oh! sweet thanks. It worked and that was an easy fix